# Why can't I assign Nothing to a variable of type Unit?

Tags: scala

If `Nothing` is a child class of `AnyVal` including `Unit`, then why I cannot assign `Nothing` to `oh`?

```
import scala.Nothing
val oh: Unit = Nothing
```

Comment: An analogy: `String` is a subtype of `String`, but you obviously can't write `val x: String = String`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's right in the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/#scala.Nothing).

> Nothing is a subtype of every other type (including scala.Null); **there exist no instances of this type**.

If there are no instances of `Nothing`, you cannot assign it to anything. It's not a value.

Comment: What is the "it" you can't assign? Your wording sounds to me like I can't `lazy val x = ???`. The other answer makes the OP's misunderstanding evident.

Answer (score 5):

`Nothing` is a type, not a value. You can only assign values to variables.

Comment: `class Nothing extends Any`. It is not just a type.

Comment: @barbara Wrong. It clearly says _`class`_, not an _`object`_.